How do I read from the virtual memory of the current process?
I have a program that injects a dll into a running process and then invoke some function in the injected dll. The goal is to read the content of the Win32ThreadInfo address in the running process, cast the struct into THREADINFO and access the the _DESKTOP field of this struct. Code below:
    DWORD RemoteFunc(LPVOID lpParam) {
    HMODULE ntdll = LoadLibraryA("ntdll.dll");
    NtQueryInformationThreadFunc NtQueryInformationThread = (NtQueryInformationThreadFunc)GetProcAddress(ntdll, "NtQueryInformationThread");
    DWORD currentProcessId=GetCurrentProcessId();
    HANDLE hThreadSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
    if (hThreadSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error: Unable to create snapshot!!! ",
        (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
        //printf("Error: Unable to create snapshot\n");
        return;
    }
    THREADENTRY32 te32;
    te32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    // Get information about the first thread
    if (!Thread32First(hThreadSnap, &te32))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error: Unable to retrieve thread information\n",
        (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE",
        MB_ICONWARNING | MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
        //printf("Error: Unable to retrieve thread information\n");
        CloseHandle(hThreadSnap);
        return;
    }
    // Loop through all threads in the snapshot
    do
    {
        // Check if the thread belongs to the specified process
        if (te32.th32OwnerProcessID == currentProcessId)
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Thread Id: %d\n",
        (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE",
         MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
            //printf("Thread ID: %d\n", te32.th32ThreadID);
            DWORD threadId = te32.th32ThreadID;
            HANDLE threadHandle = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, threadId);
            if (threadHandle == NULL) {
                    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Failed to open thread\n",
        (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE",
         MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
                    //printf("Failed to open thread.\n");
            continue;
            }
            MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Successfully open thread\n",
        (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE",
         MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
            //printf("successfully open thread\n");
            THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION tbi;
            ULONG returnLength = 0;
            NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationThread(threadHandle, ThreadBasicInformation, &tbi, sizeof(tbi), &returnLength);
            if (status == 0) {
                    //printf("TEB Base Address: %p\n", tbi.TebBaseAddress);
            HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, (DWORD)tbi.ClientId.UniqueProcess);
            //printf("UniquePID %p \n",(DWORD)tbi.ClientId.UniqueProcess);
            if (processHandle == NULL) {
                    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error: Failed to open process\n",
        (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE",
         MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
            //printf("Failed to open process.\n");
            }
            TEB2 teb;
            SIZE_T bytesRead=0;
            SIZE_T threadInfo_t=0;
            THREADINFO thread_info;
            if(ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, tbi.TebBaseAddress, &teb, sizeof(teb), &bytesRead)) {
                //printf("Win32ThreadInfo: %p\n", teb.Win32ThreadInfo);
                //printf("Sizeof threadinfo %d\n",sizeof(THREADINFO));
                if(ReadProcessMemory(processHandle,(THREADINFO*)teb.Win32ThreadInfo,&thread_info,sizeof(thread_info),&threadInfo_t))
                    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Successfully read process memory\n", (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE", MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
                    //printf("ThreadInfo %p\n", thread_info.rpdesk);
                else
                   {
                       DWORD lastError=GetLastError();
                     MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error: Unable to read Win32ThreadInfo\n",
        (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE",
         MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
         break;
                    //printf("Unable to read Win32ThreadInfo. %d\n",GetLastError());
                   }
                    }
            else {
                    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error: Failed to read TEB memory\n",
        (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE",
         MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
                //printf("Failed to read TEB memory.\n");
        }
            CloseHandle(threadHandle);
            }
            else
                MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)"Error: Could not retrieve thread information\n",
        (LPCWSTR)"FUNC STATE",
         MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | MB_DEFBUTTON2);
        }
    }
    while(Thread32Next(hThreadSnap, &te32));// Get the next thread
    // Clean up the snapshot object
    CloseHandle(hThreadSnap);
    return 0; 
}

Everything works as expected from injection to the RPC until the aspect where ReadProcessMemory is called with teb.Win32ThreadInfo as argument at which point the message box displays Error: Unable to read Win32ThreadInfo. How do I read the content of this address?
System info: Windows 11 with Intel pentium(R) silver x64 processor. Also program was executed with admin privilege.
N.B: I have no serious prior experience with windows development or reverse engineering.
Edits
Code snippet updated for clarity.

@3CxEZiVlQ thanks. That's something I could always correct but could you address the principal question if you have an answer?    Edit Also note the MessageBox is temporary and only for debugging purposes.

There's no need to use ReadProcessMemory to read from your own process. Just access the memory normally. You never showed where you got tbi from. It is likely that the values in tbi are not correct.

please provide minimal reproducible example. as noted by RaymondChen, your code is missing the essential definitions.

this might be more suitable on [reverseengineering.se]

Abuse of casting will give you more trouble than you should be able to hold.  If you need to cast a string literal to another type to pass it to a function, probably you will need a macro or function wrapper to make the appropiate string type instead.

Please, don't write dirty/unformatted code.  More, don't write snippets, but minimal, complete and reproducible code  Thanks.

Use the debugger to see the value of teb.Win32ThreadInfo. Dump the bytes at that address in the debugger. Does it work? If not, the ReadProcessMemory is working correctly. The problem is in how you calculated the address

@RaymondChen I did check the teb.Win32ThreadInfo in the dbg and it appears to be an invalid memory address at 2FBC. Alternatively, could it be a valid but restricted memory address?

If you wrote all of this code yourself, you should immediately recognize that 2fbc is not a valid address. Reading memory from the current process is a simple matter of dereferencing pointers. You don't need ReadProcessMemory. it seems that your problem isn't with reading memory from the current process, but rather with calculating the correct address to read.
